# Is it possible to ask moderators to deliberately suspend one's account for an specified time?

Tags: support, moderation, account-suspension

After seeing [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/32426/peterh) profile, 
[image: profile]

This question came to my mind.

Does there exist a way to ask moderators to suspend your account up to a certain date? ***FOR EXAMPLE*** because one has become addicted and can't do their other duty which is more important.

I think it would be better to make one. After all, If one wants to continue being here, they leave the button un-pressed.

Comment: yes, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124479/provide-a-non-derogatory-message-for-self-requested-suspensions

Comment: One option would be to give access to your account to a trusted family member, invite them to change your password and email address and not to return it until X. Yes this goes against every ounce of my infosec beliefs, but it would be effective at least

Comment: @DarrenH and all guys! That was an example! I am not addicted :]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure.

I mean, you can ask moderators for a suspension, a stack of waffles, a pot of syrup, and a pony if you feel like it. Doesn't mean they have to give 'em to you.

Suspensions are normally reserved for problematic behavior. Moderators *may*, **at their discretion**, hand them out upon request... But there are numerous reasons why they may not wish to do so:

1. Suspending a user in good standing may make other users uneasy, especially if no reason is given.
2. Past suspensions are recorded by the system, and can cause problems if problematic behavior arises in the future.
3. Moderators may simply be busy and not wish to waste time doing something that could more effectively be handled by the user themselves should they simply walk away from their keyboard.

Note that *network-wide* suspensions are even more severe, and can only be put in place by employees of Stack Exchange; we generally consider this an extreme measure and use it sparingly.

Comment: So if a mod decides to suspend the user anyway, what happens if they're discovered using a sock puppet to subvert the suspension?

Comment: Serves as a humbling reminder to everyone involved that folks often ask for things they don't really want.

Comment: But this answer says one can do this. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124484/349481 It's an alternative however...

Comment: Not actually possible for a moderator (or anyone else, without direct db manipulation) to remove *all* credentials from an account, @AHB, so that answer is either out of date or speculative anyway. You can, of course, trivially change your own password to something impossible to guess and then not save it anywhere, rendering the same effect without anyone else's assistance.

Comment: I hereby ask for a pony.

Answer (score 5):

I've been asked before - and *typically* the answer is 'no' .

Moderators arn't babysitters - we shouldn't be responsible for your lack of self control. *Typically* someone desiring a suspension has other issues which are likely to need to be handled first.

[The blog post that introduced suspensions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/83199/how-do-i-overcome-my-fear-of-speaking-with-an-accent-when-communicating-with-a-n#comment238135_83199) dosen't indicate it as a reason And well, I have *better* things to do.

If  user consistantly badgered me about it,I might suspend him for some arbitrary amount of time for *trolling*

Its worth considering that to me, this solves nothing,

> For example because one has become addicted and can't do their other duty which is more important.

You can still read the site or create another account. This would also suggest, other, deep seated issues.

Suspensions are logged and mods can see that you were. In a sense, there's long term concequences.

I'd also add that what the OP's done here is tried to get attention for himself. He's suceeded. He's in no place to demand a *specific* suspension.

Answer (score -6):

I agree with *Shog9*, and *Journeyman Geek* You can "ask" for a account to be suspended, but the answer will typically be "*No*" or "*We ...*" (or I) ".*..will investigate more into it.*"  But sometimes it gets thrown a pile of **look at later** claims and suggestions, and most accounts requested to be suspended aren't unless the claim is stated up-and-out, or more and more people are flagging the account, so if either of those are true, than it will happen, but if its like 2 people who flag that account, most of the time it won't happen.

As being a admin of one site, and a moderator of a few others (mostly game sites), you go through a lot of claims and flags that mostly aren't true.  So a lot of them assume the flag is useless, or inaccurate.

So to answer your question fully, yes you can ask a moderator to suspend an account, but I would not anticipate it to be very quick, nor for it to happen at all.  But, go for it, if you have solid proof of it, and can present enough of it to a moderator (or admin), than they have to do something because you presented them enough information to prove the the flag was accurate, and is useful.

Comment: A couple things: 1) You can't flag an account on Stack Exchange, not directly. You can flag their posts, but not the account itself. 2) The question is about a user asking _to have themselves suspended_, not users asking for other users to be suspended. Your answer reads as an answer to the latter scenario. 3) I'm really not sure what, of the parts that don't seem to be irrelevant/about a different scenario, is added upon Shog and Journeyman's answers.

Comment: This isn't asking about flags requesting *someone else's* account be suspended.  It's asking about cases where a user is requesting *their own* account be suspended.  There's nothing to "investigate" in such a case.  There's no accusation of illicit behavior.

Comment: oh, sorry, I didn't see _your account_, I thought it said _someone else's account_.

Comment: Oh, my answer would be very different if someone asked me to suspend someone elses account without a good reason. It would likely involve massive amounts of laughter, and armchair quarterbacking does not work well with moderation.  Flag *posts*. Leave the people management to the mods.